# Triggering ajax calls after ajaxOncomplete causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have defined a general ajaxComplete function to be triggered after each ajax request as follow;

```
$(document).on('pfAjaxComplete', function(event, xhr, options) {
     doStuff();
});
```

Note I use pfAjaxComplete instead of ajaxComplete to work under PrimeFaces

Now, on each ajaxcomplete the 'doStuff()' function is being called. Problem is that inside the 'doStuff()' function I trigger several ajax calls to be executed based on a PrimeFaces remoteCommand

```
function doStuff() {
  var elements = $('#wrapper').find("[id*='elements']");
  if (elements !== null && elements .length > 0) {
     $.each(elements , function(index) {
       newAjaxCallBack([{name: 'param', value: 'val'}]);
     });
  }
}
```

My remote command

```
<p:remoteCommand name="newAjaxCallBack" actionListener="#{backingBean.action}" />
```

This is working fine, the backing bean action method is being called. Problem is the new ajax callback on 'doStuff' triggers a new ajaxOnComplete event, which makes sense of course but then it gets me on an infinite loop. Had tried to work it out but couldn't find any solution to it.

Any ideas or suggestions? Would there be a way to send a parameter on the newAjaxCallBack and then detecting it on the ajaxComplete function so as to avoid the doStuff call? Thanks!

Comment: Does `newAjaxCallback` call `doStuff()`?

Comment: Well shouldn;t the complete event check to see if it is type **XYZ** before calling the doStuff?

Comment: @Jack no, just trriggers a backing bean action method... but this is taken as another ajax call so it loops

Comment: @epascarello indeed, but I been having trouble to work this out :)

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution would be to append additional parameters to your calls on which you don't want another action to be executed.

If you choose a "paremeter" that is not used on the target page, it won't care about it.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, options) {
    if (options.url.indexOf("noStuff=true") != -1){
       alert("Ignoring Ajax Request from noStuff");
        return;
    }
    doStuff();
});

function doStuff(){
   alert("doing stuff");   
    //another fake ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://google.de", 
        data: [
            {name: 'param', value: 'val'},
            {name: 'noStuff', value: 'true'}
        ]
     });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3kwhn0kx/

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working, solution was similar to @dognose one, in my case I had to use the data primefaces handled, this way;

```
...
$.each(elements , function(index) {
       newAjaxCallBack([{name: 'dontcall', value: 'true'}]);
     });
...
```

and then:

```
$(document).on('pfAjaxComplete', function(event, xhr, options) {
    if (xhr.pfSettings.data.indexOf('dontcall') !== -1) {
        return;
    }
    doStuff();
});
```

As you may see, I'm using the pfSettings object, which has an attribute 'data' that is basically a string with info related to the request including params, so if parameter present, don't do anything.